# AWS opsworks createApp api won't work with provided password and username with bitbucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am trying to use aws node.js sdk inorder to create an app in OPSWorks.

My repository is at bitbucket and it is private.

I want to use the AWS api with my account password instead of SSH.

This is the code:

```
  var appParams = {
        Name: 'Demo app',
        StackId: userData.Stacks.stackId,
        Type: 'nodejs',
        AppSource: {
            Password: '*******',
            Type: 'git',
            Url: 'https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/myUserName/demofresh.git',
            Username: 'myUserName'
        }
    }
    opsworks.createApp(appParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            callback(err);
        else{
            console.log(data);
            callback(data);
        }
    });
```

For some reason i am getting this error all the time when running an instance with this app.

Error:

```
---- Begin output of git ls-remote https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/myUserName/demofresh.git HEAD ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myUserName@bitbucket.org': No such device or address
---- End output of git ls-remote https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/myUserName/demofresh.git HEAD ----
Ran git ls-remote https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/myUserName/demofresh.git HEAD returned 128
```

I have also tried to change the url to:

```
Url: 'https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/myUserName/demofresh.git',
```

But then i got an error that it doesn't have a username field.

Some how it is not reading the password i have provided.

I have used DescribeApps with success just to make sure that the password and username were saved in the application at amazon servers.

So maybe there is a problem in the AWS API?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue and *believe* that I found the resolution by RTFM at AWS OpsWorks:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-creating.html

In that doc, it talks about setting up a private repo, and specifying a different repo connection string:

> Private repository–Use the SSH read/write format shown in these
>   examples:
>
> - Github repositories: git@github.com:project/repository.
> - Repositories on a Git server: user@server:project/repository

So, I went into bitbucket, copied my SSH Connection string and set it up like this:

```
git@bitbucket.org:repo_owner/project.git
```

Additionally, the document indicates two additional settings for git repos:

> Selecting Git under Source Control displays two additional optional
>   settings:
>
> **Repository SSH key**
>
> You must specify a deploy SSH key to access private
>   Git repositories. For Git submodules, the specified key must have
>   access to those submodules. For more information, see Using Repository
>   SSH Keys.
>
> **Important**
>
> The deploy SSH key cannot require a password; AWS OpsWorks
>   has no way to pass it through. Branch/Revision If the repository has
>   multiple branches, AWS OpsWorks downloads the master branch by
>   default. To specify a particular branch, enter the branch name, SHA1
>   hash, or tag name. To specify a particular commit, enter the full
>   40-hexdigit commit id.